# floating div loses parents class with clear:both;?

Tags: html, css-float

I am having a little trouble trying to put a border around both rows. It currently only does the first row.

I have used clear:both; for a new row of divs but its seems to take away the parent divs style with the border.

```
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    width: 90%;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">
        Row 1, Column 1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">
        Row 1, Column 2
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">
        Row 2, Column 1
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:150px;">
        Row 2, Column 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the same HTML structure, simply add a `clear:both` container after your last div. http://jsfiddle.net/7cptj/

Comment: Thanks was a bit of a DOH moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a clearing div after your second row. That should resolve your issue.

The reason being is that when you float an element, you are more or less breaking it out of its parent element. `clear: both` places a blank element relatively below to your floated divs, thus keeping the "space" that the floated divs normally would occupy.